# How to solve this SQL WHERE (date and exception) Syntax Error?

Tags: sql

Could you take a look at the query below please? I tried to convert my access table into a SQL query with very little knowledge (for now).

The last line seems to be wrong when I execute it.

```
USE [idb_datastore]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[idb_dataSTORESQLTesting] 
AS 
IF OBJECT_ID( 'idb_datastore.dbo.[Testing]','U' ) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE idb_datastore.dbo.[Testing];

SELECT dbo.REC_HDR.F91 AS [PO Number], 
hd.F1032 AS [Trs Number], 
hd.F76 AS [Order Date], 
hd.F27 AS [Vendor ID], 
hd.F334 AS [Vendor Name], 
hd.F1246 AS [Delivery Date], 
hd.F1127 AS [Operator Short Name], 
hd.F1068 AS State, 
hd.F1067 AS Status

FROM SMSSERVER01.STORESQL.dbo.REC_HDR hd

WHERE hd.F91 Is Not Null AND hd.F76 >= Convert(datetime, ’2017/01/01’ ) AND 
hd.F1068 NOT like ’Voided’
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MchQf.png)

Comment: Change those curvy quote symbols to single quote version, `'`.

Comment: @Parfait same result

Comment: I find that hard to believe as your error points to exact curve quote symbol.

Answer (score 0):

SQL datetime format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

change the final line to this

```
Convert(datetime, '2017-01-01' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the where sentence to this

> WHERE hd.F91 Is Not Null 
>   AND hd.F76 >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/13/2013', 101) 
>   AND hd.F1068 NOT like '%Voided%'

Comment: Thanks for your quickness, I'll try it. What does the 101 stand for?

Comment: this is the documentation link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017, 1 101 U.S. 1 = mm/dd/yy
101 = mm/dd/yyyy